# Flutter How to connect a Flutter Wi-Fi Direct printer

Tags: flutter, dart, networking, printing

I am implementing a method to discover peripherals using wifi.
I did a search and found the `network_info_plus` and `lan_scanner` packages.

However, the IPs of my printer and router are different.

For example, the IP of the printer is 192.168.1.100 and the IP of the wifi is 192.168.10.100.

If you search for a printer using the printing package, the printer is normally found.

My source is to count IPs and subnets and the number of devices discovered around them. Thanks in advance for your help.

How about discovering peripherals in different IP bands?

***Source***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lan_scanner/lan_scanner.dart';
import 'package:network_info_plus/network_info_plus.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Set<DeviceModel> hosts = Set<DeviceModel>();
  LanScanner scanner = LanScanner();

  var wifiIP;
  var subnet;

  var _ip;
  var _sub;
  var _count;

  void searchDevices() async {
    wifiIP = await (NetworkInfo().getWifiIP());
    subnet = "192.168.1";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('network'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          hosts.clear();
          searchDevices();

          var stream = scanner.preciseScan(
            wifiIP,
            progressCallback: (ProgressModel progress) {
              print('${progress.percent * 100}% ${wifiIP!}.${progress.currIP}');
            },
          );

          //  print('Host Length : ${hosts.length}');

          stream.listen((DeviceModel device) {
            if (device.exists) {
              setState(() {
                hosts.add(device);
                print('Host Length : ${hosts.length}');
              });
            }
          });
        },
        tooltip: 'Start scanning',
        child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 100,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  'wifiIP : $_ip;',
                ),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        _ip = wifiIP;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text('show IP'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 100,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  'subnet : $_sub;',
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    setState(() {
                      _sub = subnet;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text('show subnet'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 100,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Device Count : $_count;',
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    setState(() {
                      _count = hosts.length;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text('show Device Count'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```